# Updating 10 rows based on primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains 1000000 records and I want to update 10 records from that based on primary key and my [date-time] is the primary key column in my table where the update condition is like this:

```
update table 
   set speed='0.000000' 
 where [date-time]>'2014-08-06 21:33:01.000'
   and [date-time]<'2014-08-06 21:38:32.000'
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Besides that, you mention `mssql` in the title but `mysql` in the tags, which is it? Also you mention updating `two` rows in the title but in your question you say `10`?

Comment: The column name `date-time` needs to be escaped: use [date-time] instead.

Comment: so again, what's the exact problem, the query syntax seems fine now, is it that `where [date-time]>'2014-08-06 21:33:01.000' and [date-time]<'2014-08-06 21:38:32.000'` can affect more than 10 rows? But then if it does, which rows would you want to update and which to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE TOP (10) table 
   set speed='0.000000' 
 where [date-time]>'2014-08-06 21:33:01.000'
   and [date-time]<'2014-08-06 21:38:32.000'
```

If you need more control over which 10 you need to update, you'll have to do something like a sub-query:

```
UPDATE table 
   set speed='0.000000' 
 where [date-time] IN ( SELECT [date-time] 
                        FROM table
                        WHERE [date-time]>'2014-08-06 21:33:01.000'
                            AND [date-time]<'2014-08-06 21:38:32.000'
                        ORDER BY [date-time] DESC  )
```